# SAPUI5 - SmartFilterBar "filterchange" method not triggering for custom controls(SearchField,MultiComboBox)

Tags: sapui5

When custom control is used in `SmartFilterBar` even after selection of item from custom control, the adopted filter number is not changing and Variant Save button not getting enabled.

```
<smartFilterBar:customControl>
    <SearchField enableSuggestions="true" suggest="onSuggest" 
    suggestionItems="{oModel>/results}" liveChange="onSearch">
        <suggestionItems>
            <SuggestionItem text="{oModel>Key}" key="{oModel>Value}"/>
        </suggestionItems>
    </SearchField>
</smartFilterBar:customControl>
```

Comment: Have you configured the key for the ControlConfiguration in your smartFilterBar?

Comment: Yes, key is configured correctly for the field

Answer (score 0):

The control "SearchField" doesn't have a "Change" event, only a "LiveChange" event. Unfortunately the smartfilterbar fires only a "Change" event itself for controls with "Change" events.

For the control "MultiCombobox" it would work, as it has a "Change" event, but unfortunately it is fired before the actual change is done (in this case the event "SelectionChange" is fired, which is ignored by the smartfilterbar).

Answer (score 0):

You can try set property **liveMode** of SmartFilterBar to true (default set "false")